# angular weirdness with element.click and $location.search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Here is the problem

```
<div id="my-id" ng-click="moveOn(10)">Click me</div>
```

In the directive I have

```
scope.moveOn = function (val) {
    $location.search('id', val);
}
```

And finally in the parent of this directive I listen for a change of this `id`

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $routeParams.id;
 }, function (newId, oldId) {
     ...
 });
```

This setup works great, after the `$location.search` is called the `$watch`er is triggered immediately. But now I also have a directive which does it slightly different, as follows:

```
element.find('#my-id').click(function (val) {
    $location.search('id', val);
});
```

In the template there is no `ng-click`!

In this situation I can also see that the call to `$location.search` is made, but now it takes a very long time (a couple of seconds) before the watcher goes off.

So for some reason there must be a difference between `ngClick` and binding to a click event. Any suggestions what might be going on here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating angular within an event that is outside of angular.

Try using `$apply` to notify angular of the change so it can run a digest

```
element.find('#my-id').click(function (val) {
    scope.$apply(function(){
       $location.search('id', val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Pfff, thats it, you saved my day. Thanks!!